# Website seems to execute old code even though it has a new class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Deployed MVC5 app manually (ie all source code) to IIS directory (c:\inetpub\wwwroot....) Win Server 2016, IIS 10.

The website runs fine. I found a bug. I fixed it and copied the fixed class file to the correct location in c:\inetpub\wwwroot.... Then I start/stop the website. But, the website still shows the "older" behavior. I verified the class file (.cs) was updated with the correct, tested, fix. I even ran Chrome in incognito mode.

Any suggestions? Is this a caching issue on the server?

Thanks!

Comment: "the fixed class"...are you copying the .cs file to the web server?

Comment: @PaulAbbott .... yes, the .cs file

Comment: Check C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\Temporary Internet Files folder and delete folder named after your application. Also make sure you copied bin folder to inetpub

Comment: @PankajKapare I copied the bin folder and it worked! There wasn't anything in the temp folder. If you want to officially answer the question I'll reward your statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you were copying just .cs file to c:\inetpub\wwwroot those changes will not be picked automatically. You need to copy updated binaries i.e. bin folder and its contents to c:\inetpub\wwwroot.